# Keep getting an error #index is missing a template for request formats: text/html", however, the index.html.erb exists

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new to rails and am having an issue building a blog tutorial. I started a project last week and had it working, but decided to try to run through it again.

The problem seems to be when I am trying to set the index to the "Welcome" Controller that I made. It appears that the file doesn't exist even though it appears to be there. I tried to add the index to it when i generated the controller and also have tried to add all of the stuff manually with no avail. It likely will be something silly but I have searched many articles trying to find a solution and they all said that you just had to make the index file that goes along with the controller.

Please see attached file with my file structure and the route file. Not sure what else would be helpful in debugging. Thank you in advance for your help. This has been making me go in circle for hours, tried new projects, new project names, new controller names, everything (at least a newbie could think of :D)!

Current file structure and routes:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Can you also attach the controller and the `index.html.erb` please - as code samples, not as pictures :)
I normally would say it's a problem with the naming of your files (often it's just an s that was forgotten) but from the picture it seems fine.

Comment: Hi! Could you post the error you get as well?

Comment: show your controller, and the full error message

Comment: Hello everyone, first off thank you for responding back to my question. I will definitely look more into the help page going forward to ensure that I comply with the rules going forward. 

Anyways, I tried everything I could think of and reformatted my PC and everything works fine now. It sounds dramatic, however, my PC didn't have anything of value on it so it wasn't hard for me to do. I spent a few days trying to get it resolved and even uninstalled ruby and all its dependencies. Glad it's working again, sorry I couldn't contribute something more valuable!